# How to still get the xmlhttprequest response text even with a http error response

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get to know why the response I get is HTTP Error 401 (Unauthorized). The API should respond with some text on why the request basically get denied, but I can't see this as the whole script just stops.
So basically this is the url opening:

```
var res = xhr.send();
console.log(res);
```

And I'm trying to console log after, which doesn't work obviously. Someone knows a bypass?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked the Network developer tab?

Comment: Ah, thank you! @Pointy

Comment: Note if you wanted to programmatically get the text it would be in `xhr.responseText` it isnt returned from `send()`

Comment: Ahh, thanks! @PatrickEvans didn't know that haha